# save folder in source to disk in chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I want to save all the files of a specific source folder in chrome to a local folder, I found [this](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3) but it seems can't do the job, I know I could save the file one by one, but since there are various files, mistake could happen and it's not boring to save one by one , so I want to know is there any way that I could save a folder to a local folder?

Thanks

[image]